# Device on WiFi range extender not avaiable via router's own WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-extender

- **Router**:  Motorola MG8702.
- **Range Extender**: Wavlink AC1200.
- **Problem device**: Meross garage door opener controller (pushbutton simulator for existing opener).

Wavlink is configured as range extender (garage is 150 feet from house), using same SSIDs for 2.4G and 5G as the Motorola router's SSIDs. Internet access via the range extender works. The Meross device is 10 feet from the range extender. Apple Home works only when my phone is near the range extender. From the house, Apple Home cannot see the device.

Via router admin on the Motorola router, the Meross device is visible as a DHCP client, but Apple Home says the device is unavailable.

How do I get Apple Home to control the garage door via the router's WiFi as well as the range extender's WiFi?

Wavlink setup is as "Gateway (recommended)". All this is set up on the Motorola guest WiFi with IP addresses in range `192.168.50.xxx`.

Comment: Looks like the problem is Apple Home.  Meross vendor app works anywhere in wifi range.  Haven't left my own wifi range yet to test further.